# How to add option to select form as received from AJAX request in PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, jquery-ajaxq

What is method to adding option to select box data received by AJAX

HTML:

`<select id="options"></select>`

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajax/addCustDetail.php",
  data: {customerId},
  cache: false,
  success: function(html)
  {
    $("#options").html(html);
  } 
});
```

Comment: What is there in the html you're receiving

Comment: Please let us know how the response looks like?? Is it a JSON object or an array?

Comment: You're doing it correctly. Your php just probably returns wrong value, as in your case it should return for example `'<option value="9">Billy</option>'`

Comment: what is your response sample? just option value or markup of an option?

Comment: To _"add"_ options, you might want to use `$('#options').append(html)`. See http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP Side Code :

```
$cid=$_POST['cid'];
$query="SELECT * from customer_shipping_address WHERE STransNo=$cid";        
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<option value=".$row['TransSlNo'].">".$row['ShipName']."</option>" ;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this:

1. By returning the string from `addCustDetail.php` like:

   ```
   $response = '<option value="1">One</option><option value="2">Two</option>';
   ```

and this `$response` is retuerned, in that case you can simply use it in jquery like:

```
    $("#options").html(html);
```

2. If you are returning an json array from `addCustDetail.php`, in that case you have parse it in jquery and iterate it and create the options and then add them in the select.

Comment: Ya, I know, may be OP is not returning the right value from `addCustDetail.php` and I am trying to explain the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can append children to the select element like this:

First, add an id to the select element:

```
<select id="myselect"></select>
```

Then append children like this:

```
var selectElement = document.getElementById("myselect");
var newOption = document.createElement("option");
newOption.innerHTML = "New option!";
selectElement.appendChild(newOption);
```

Assuming you recieve an array from ajax request now you can make a loop and use above code to add options.
Example:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
   var newOption = document.createElement("option");
   newOption.innerHTML = response[i].name;
   newOption.setAttribute("value", response[i].value);
   selectElement.appendChild(newOption);
}
```

Comment: OP is clearly getting the new option data via AJAX so your examples aren't exactly a good fit